# Limit the total space in every user

Tags: buddypress

I use the buddypress + rtmedia plugins to create website.

And I met a problem that how can I **limit the total space** in every user ?

**for example**

every user has 10MB to upload the video,photo,music in their profile.

or

every user can upload 10 photos in their profile.

can that do it via theme`s functions.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a task that can be easily tackled using `wp_handle_upload` and `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` (e.g.: [Give users a maximum upload capacity; limit the number of files a user can upload OR limit the number of files per upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47580/give-users-a-maximum-upload-capacity-limit-the-number-of-files-a-user-can-uploa)).

Luckily someone already did this, as a plugin: [Upload Quota per User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-quota-per-user). It's pretty old and seems unmaintained but tested on WP 4.9.9 it works.