# How do I set a maximum upload size for a specific user role (Editor)

Tags: users, uploads, media-library

In Wordpress I want to be able to restrict each Editor to be able to upload 500 mb of different files in total. Is that possible?

Thanks 
Kasper

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47580/give-users-a-maximum-upload-capacity-limit-the-number-of-files-a-user-can-uploa

Comment: Hi Fuxia, thanks for the link, seems to work ... almost:). When I test the code, everything works fine, both with the single upload and the multiple upload, but the files which I upload looses their format (.jpg, .mp4, .gif etc.) and are not recognized in the Media Library. So no preview. When I remove the code from the post you referred to, everything works fine. Any idea why?